# Parsley doesn't work after appending html

Tags: javascript, html, parsley.js

I tried following code, but it doesn't notify when there's no data in the input box. When I directly add this content (without) appending it works. What am I doing wrong here

```
var output = "<form class=\"registration__form\">\n"+
            "<ul class=\"form-fields\">\n"+
            "<li>\n"+
            "<input type=\"text\" name=\"msisdn\" id=\"field-msisdn\" placeholder=\"Enter your&nbsp;MSISDN\" autofocus required data-parsley-required-message=\"Please insert your MSISDN\">\n"+
            "</li>\n"+
            "<li>\n"+
            "<input type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn--large btn--fill btn--full\" value=\"Reset&nbsp;PIN\" onclick=\"submitMSISDN($('#field-msisdn').val());\"/>\n"+
            "</li>\n"+
            "</ul>\n"+
       "</form>";


$("#gadgetBody").empty();
        $("#gadgetBody").append(output);
        $("#gadgetBody").parsley();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `parsley()` on the form, not on whatever contains the form.

In your case: `$("#gadgetBody form").parsley()` should work.